# Creating an account key pair outside of using eosjs

Tags: cleos, eosjs, keys, public-key, private-key

Hello Guys is there any method through which I can create a valid EOSIO key pair without using EOSJS, If that's not possible can any one explain how does eosjs-ecc create those keys and can I replicate that process.

Answer (score 0):

`cleos create key --to-console` will generate and output a keypair in your console. The source code for this is in https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/programs/cleos/main.cpp#L2543 and https://github.com/EOSIO/fc/blob/ff56d25e587f8131cfde06f1eb61baa899bc8a89/include/fc/crypto/private_key.hpp

Looking at EOSJS source code is probably easier than the C++ code above: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs/blob/master/src/PrivateKey.ts